# Incorrect sum of array in browser

Tags: javascript, sum, decimal

While fixing an validation error preventing user from saving with the message

> "You have 100%. You need to have 100%!"

I have ran into very interesting issue happening in both Firefox 34 and IE 11:

```
0.57+8.36+3.36+0.19
```

gives in Firefox and Chrome

```
12.479999999999999
```

And in IE

```
12.479999999999998
```

If no one wants to calculate, correct result would be
12.48

I will fix issue now by using Math.Round in reduce function to "correct" value on every step, but real question is, what is cause of this at the first look (of naive user) incorrect behavior?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4pLrewy/2/)

Note that I have originally discovered issue by trying to sum an Array:

```
[ 0.57, 8.36, 3.36, 0.19, 39.29, 6.37, 17.24, 0.16, 2.07, 0.04, 22.36].sum()
[ 0.57, 8.36, 3.36, 0.19, 39.29, 6.37, 17.24, 0.16, 2.07, 0.04, 22.36].reduce(function(item,item2){return item+item2})
```

Comment: Floating-point arithmetic is subject to rounding errors.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: thanks, good one, and very important lesson for the team! :)

Comment: Round to a suitable precision when doing comparisons of calculated values (say one significant digit more than you need), or allow +/- to a suitable tolerance.

Comment: Interesting -- and unexpected -- that IE (JScript) differs from Chrome (V8) and Firefox (SpiderMonkey). Even IE11: http://jsbin.com/lisina/1 Microsoft seems to be out on their own on this one (quelle shock), Java agrees with V8 and SpiderMonkey.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder—interesting perhaps, but why is that surprising or even remarkable? Is IE non–compliant with either ECMA-262 or IEEE 754?

Comment: @RobG: In my naïveté, I would have expected MS to be able to implement IEEE-754 double-precision floating point correctly. I don't *know* that they're the ones who got it wrong, of course, because I haven't done the math. But as Mozilla, Google, and Oracle/Sun all agree on a result, let's just say I think it's probably MS who's messed it up...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder—just because IE is different doesn't mean it's wrong, there is likely sufficient ambiguity in the standard for them to both be right. For the record, `12.479999999999998 === 12.479999999999999` returns *true*, so at least as far as IEEE 754 floats are concerned, the values are identical. Try this clj thread: [*IE and IEE 754*](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.javascript/xRJESD4ohfA).